# Why do I get the MySQL Error "Query was empty"?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$Section = $_REQUEST['section'];
$Subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$type = $_REQUEST['type'];
$Start_date1 = isset($_REQUEST['startTxt'])?($_REQUEST['startTxt']):"";
$Venue = isset($_REQUEST['venTxt'])?($_REQUEST['venTxt']):"";
$Facilitator = isset($_REQUEST['faciTxt'])?($_REQUEST['faciTxt']):"";
$Level = isset($_REQUEST['lvlLst'])?($_REQUEST['lvlLst']):"";
$Date1 = $_REQUEST['date1'];

if(isset($_REQUEST['EDIT']))
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE service SET Start_date='$Date1', Venue='$Venue', Facilitator='$Faci' WHERE ServiceID ='$id'");
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Changes have been save!");';
    echo 'window.location="Admin_RecSchedMapLst.php";';
    echo '</script>';
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

When I click save it returns "Error: Query was empty" - why is this?

Comment: Where is $sql declared? Are you sure you didnt mean to assign it on the line above?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're calling `mysql_query()` twice, once with a non-existent `$sql` parameter:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE service SET Start_date='$Date1', Venue='$Venue', Facilitator='$Faci' WHERE ServiceID ='$id'");
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
```

should be:

```
if (!mysql_query("UPDATE service SET Start_date='$Date1', Venue='$Venue', Facilitator='$Faci' WHERE ServiceID ='$id'"))
```

You're also not escaping your input, leaving you open to SQL injection.
You should use bound parameters ideally, or at the very least run your parameters through [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

For example:

```
$Date1 = mysql_real_escape_string($Date1, $conn);
```

Answer (score 5):

Please, for the love of the internet, don't built an SQL query yourself. Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting the $sql variable and calling mysql_query() twice.