# MySQL Query Was Empty

Tags: php, mysql

This is meant to get data from the URL and submit it to the database and it gives an error:
Query was empty;

I put some more things in there to test and yes, it gives the values of the variables that i have set. Thanks in advance

```
<?php
require 'variables.php';
if(empty($_REQUEST['Key']) || empty($_REQUEST['Computer']) || empty($_REQUEST['Panel'])){
die("Nothing was given for me to give back :(");
}else{
$key = $_REQUEST['Key'];
$computer = $_REQUEST['Computer'];
$panel = $_REQUEST['Panel'];
$insertquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO keys (Key, PC, Panel) VALUES ('".$key."', '".$computer."', '".$panel."')");
$sql = mysql_query($insertquery);
if($sql){
    echo "good ". mysql_error();
}else{
    echo "bad ". mysql_error();
    echo "<br />".$key." ".$computer." ".$panel."";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636032/why-do-i-get-the-mysql-error-query-was-empty?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You are calling **`mysql_query()`** twice. That's the problem

Do like this

```
<?php
require 'variables.php';
if(empty($_REQUEST['Key']) || empty($_REQUEST['Computer']) || empty($_REQUEST['Panel'])){
die("Nothing was given for me to give back :(");
}else{
$key = $_REQUEST['Key'];
$computer = $_REQUEST['Computer'];
$panel = $_REQUEST['Panel'];
$insertquery = "INSERT INTO keys (Key, PC, Panel) VALUES ('".$key."', '".$computer."', '".$panel."')";
$sql = mysql_query($insertquery);
if($sql){
    echo "good ". mysql_error();
}else{
    echo "bad ". mysql_error();
    echo "<br />".$key." ".$computer." ".$panel."";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: I tried that, dont know why i put mysql_query() twice though haha.but removeing the second query gives me You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys (Key, PC, Panel) VALUES ('1', '2', '3')' at line 1

Comment: @user2802113 See Jason OOO's answer

Answer (score 0):

1.Your query contains two reserved words `key` and `keys` you need to enclose them with backticks (`):

```
INSERT INTO `keys` (`Key`, PC, Panel)
```

You can avoid this by changing column names.

2.You are vulnerable to SQL injection, switch to PDO or MySQLi and use parameterized query.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't cause the "query was empty" error, it causes a different error.

Answer (score 0):

**key** is a mysql sensitive word (reserved word). - [read more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html)

You are calling mysql_query twice aswell.
Your SQL query should look something like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO keys (`Key`, `PC`, `Panel`) VALUES ('".$key."', '".$computer."', '".$panel."')");
```

That should hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this code:

```
$insertquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO keys (Key, PC, Panel) VALUES ('".$key."', '".$computer."', '".$panel."')");
$sql = mysql_query($insertquery);
```

Your're passing in the result of `mysql_query` into `mysql_query`. You should change that to:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `keys` (`Key`, PC, Panel) VALUES ('$key', '$computer', '$panel')");
```

Btw you need to escape your data (SQL injection..) and use a new API for database connections (MySQLi/PDO).

Answer (score 0):

correct code

```
    <?php
    require 'variables.php';
    if(empty($_REQUEST['Key']) || empty($_REQUEST['Computer']) || empty($_REQUEST['Panel'])){
    die("Nothing was given for me to give back :(");
    }else{
    $key = $_REQUEST['Key'];
    $computer = $_REQUEST['Computer'];
    $panel = $_REQUEST['Panel'];
    $insertquery = ("INSERT INTO keys (Key, PC, Panel) VALUES ('".$key."', '".$computer."', '".$panel."')");
    $sql = mysql_query($insertquery);
    if($sql){
        echo "good ". mysql_error();
    }else{
        echo "bad ". mysql_error();
        echo "<br />".$key." ".$computer." ".$panel."";
    }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem of a database connection and you are using mysql_query two times which is not necessary. as far as the reserved key word are concerned try writing them like

```
$insertquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO keys (`Key`, `PC`, `Panel`) VALUES ('".$key."', '".$computer."', '".$panel."')");
```