# how to separate date,month,year form stored db in dob field

Tags: php, sql

"SELECT * FROM waiting EXTRACT(YEAR from dob) AS birthyear, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dob) AS birthmonth, EXTRACT(DAY FROM dob) AS birthday WHERE `mem_id`='ADT56639'"

Comment: What type `dob`? What is the database you're using? Assume MySQL and DATE or DATETIME, just do YEAR(dob), MONTH(dob), DAY(dob)

Comment: (sql)phpmyadmin dob is date

Comment: The `extract()` expressions should be in the `select` clause, not at the end of the query.

Answer (score 2):

this one work

```
 SELECT
    YEAR(dob) AS birthyear,
    MONTH(dob) AS birthmonth,
    DAY(dob) AS birthday * FROM waiting
```

Comment: you have any idea it cant store in db

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
      EXTRACT(YEAR from dob) AS birthyear, 
      EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dob) AS birthmonth, 
      EXTRACT(DAY FROM dob) AS birthday 
FROM 
waiting
```

Comment: i get error (Query Was Empty!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636032/why-do-i-get-the-mysql-error-query-was-empty

Answer (score 1):

If you want more info then [click On](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day)

```
SELECT  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dob) AS birthyear,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dob) AS birthmonth,
EXTRACT(DAY FROM dob) AS birthday, waiting.* FROM 
waiting
```

Comment: i get an error is query was empty!

Comment: again i get error from this code (query was empty)

Comment: HI, i am not a getting any error, please check aain

Comment: it does not store in db

Comment: then how i get an result for this

Comment: u c in w3schools extract function

Comment: Please, check now all is well

Comment: Hi, please execute updated query

Comment: u get result ah? wat do u understanded from w3school abt extract function explain me.......